# Upgrade issues from Pyside (QT4.8) to PySide2 (QT5.x) for tornado/flask project

Tags: python, tornado, pyside2

I am trying to upgrade my python webserver project to a new QT version (qt4.8 => qt5.x), but the webserver (tornado/flask) is not delivering the website any more. And i don't really know how to debug it.

**My main setup is:**

- Python running on Debian 10 client in VirtualBox (before: Debian 8)
- Python3.5        (could be upgraded if necessary)
- PySide2 (QT5.x)  (before: PySide - QT4.8)
- Tornado4.2       (i am willing to upgrade, but the newer versions changed the way the event
  loop works and i couldn't get it to work in the past)
- Flask

**My problem / What i tried**

- The webbrowser doesn't receive the website (screen is blanc), but also doesn't time out. This can go on for minutes
- sudo ss -ltp:

  - LISTEN 0   128   127.0.0.1:5000   0.0.0.0:*   users:(("python3",pid=2037,fd=96))

**Code structure**

- The tornado/flask part is running in a single QThread()
- The "main task" runs some general code every 2seconds

**main.py**

```py
#!/usr/bin/python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import sys
from PySide2.QtCore import QCoreApplication, QTimer
from T_CTRL import T_CTRL

def main():
    # create application
    app = QCoreApplication(sys.argv)
    app.aboutToQuit.connect(app.deleteLater)
    app.processEvents()
        
    # create object for general code
    ctrl = T_CTRL() 
           
    # create my simple timer task
    timerT = QTimer()
    timerT.start(2000)
    timerT.timeout.connect( ctrl.myTimeTask )    
    
    # run application and create main event handler
    return app.exec_()
    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

**T_CTRL.py**

```py
#!/usr/bin/python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from PySide2 import QtCore
from PySide2.QtCore import QThread, QCoreApplication
from T_Clean_Exit import T_Clean_Exit
from T_Web_Worker import ThreadWorker


class T_CTRL(QtCore.QObject): 
    def __init__(self):   
        
        print ("init T_CTRL")
        
        # create thread objects for the webserver
        self.t = QThread()
        self.worker = ThreadWorker()
    
        # configure the main application to handle quit signals correctly
        self.cleanExit = T_Clean_Exit(self.t)
        
        # create thread  for the webserver
        self.worker.moveToThread(self.t)        
       
        # connect signals/slots to start the webserver
        self.t.started.connect(self.worker.startServer)
                
        # connect signals/slots for the shutdown of thread and webserver
        self.worker.sigServerShutdownFinished.connect(self.t.quit)
        self.worker.sigServerShutdownFinished.connect(self.worker.deleteLater)
        self.cleanExit.sigShutdown.connect(self.t.quit)
        self.cleanExit.sigShutdown.connect(self.worker.deleteLater)
        self.t.finished.connect(self.t.deleteLater)    
        
        # start the webserver thread
        self.t.start()
      
        # connect signals/slots for the shutdown of the webserver
        self.cleanExit.sigShutdown.connect(self.worker.requestServerStop) 
   

    # -------------------------------------------------------------------------
    # Timer Task
    # -------------------------------------------------------------------------
    def myTimeTask(self):        
        print ("Slow main task...")        
        # allow other events to be run
        QCoreApplication.processEvents()
```

**T_Web_Worker.py**

```py
#!/usr/bin/python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-


from PySide2 import QtCore
from flask import Flask, render_template
from tornado.wsgi import WSGIContainer
from tornado.httpserver import HTTPServer
from tornado.ioloop import IOLoop
import time

class ThreadWorker(QtCore.QObject): 
    
    # init flask & tornado
    app = Flask(__name__)
    http_server = None
    
    # stuff for server shutdown    
    MAX_WAIT_SECONDS_BEFORE_SHUTDOWN = 2
    sigServerShutdownFinished = QtCore.Signal()
      
    # -------------------------------------------------------------------------
    # constructor()
    # -------------------------------------------------------------------------      
    def __init__(self):  #, log):
        super(ThreadWorker, self).__init__()       

    # -------------------------------------------------------------------------
    # Start the web server
    # ------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
    def startServer(self):         
        self.http_server = HTTPServer(WSGIContainer(self.app))        
        self.http_server.listen(5000, "127.0.0.1")        
        IOLoop.instance().start()

    # -------------------------------------------------------------------------
    # Route: "/"
    # ------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
    @app.route('/')
    def index():
       return render_template('index.html')
          
    # -------------------------------------------------------------------------
    # Route: "/*.html"
    # -------------------------------------------------------------------------       
    @app.route('/<path>.html')
    def static_html_file(path):
        return render_template(path + ".html")    
        
    # -------------------------------------------------------------------------
    # Request a shutdown of the webserver.
    # -------------------------------------------------------------------------
    @QtCore.Slot()
    def requestServerStop(self):
        IOLoop.instance().add_callback(self.shutdownServer)       
     
    # -------------------------------------------------------------------------
    # Stop the web server
    # Don't call this function directly. Always use "requestServerStop()"
    # -------------------------------------------------------------------------
    def shutdownServer(self):
        self.http_server.stop()
    
        io_loop = IOLoop.instance()
    
        deadline = time.time() + self.MAX_WAIT_SECONDS_BEFORE_SHUTDOWN
    
        def stop_loop():
            now = time.time()
            if now < deadline and (io_loop._callbacks or io_loop._timeouts):
                io_loop.add_timeout(now + 1, stop_loop)
            else:
                io_loop.stop()
        stop_loop() 
        
        # server has been stopped, now stop the thread        
        self.sigServerShutdownFinished.emit()
```

**T_Clean_Exit.py**

```py
#!/usr/bin/python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from PySide2 import QtCore
from PySide2.QtCore import QCoreApplication
import signal
from functools import partial


# -------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Properly shutdown the qpplication
# -------------------------------------------------------------------------
class T_Clean_Exit(QtCore.QObject):   
        
    sigShutdown = QtCore.Signal()
    
    def __init__(self, objThread): 
        # init 
        super(T_Clean_Exit, self).__init__()
        self.objThread = objThread # save instance object of thread

        # connect quit signals to sigint_handler
        signal.signal(signal.SIGINT,  partial(self.sigint_handler, str1=""))
        signal.signal(signal.SIGTERM, partial(self.sigint_handler, str1=""))
        #signal.signal(signal.SIGBREAK, sigint_handler)

    def sigint_handler(self, signal, frame, str1):
        #Handler for the SIGINT signal 

        # send Shtudownsignals -> 1) server shutdown 2) thread shutdown
        self.sigShutdown.emit()
        QCoreApplication.processEvents()

        # waiting for the server and thread to shutdown        
        ret = self.objThread.wait(5000)                       # wait for thread to close, but max 5000ms
        QCoreApplication.processEvents()
   
        # everything has been shut down, now quit the applicaiton            
        QCoreApplication.quit()
```

It would be really great if you could give me some guidance.

Comment: please provide a [mre]

Comment: Thanks I read the link and will provide the example tonight

Comment: I stripped down my code to a running example. I hope it meets the rules of the forum.

Comment: Update: The script and tornado server work fine if i run the script from the terminal with: `python <script>`. The problems i described exists, if i run it from my Spyder (v4) IDE in an IPython console. After googling, i understand that IPython uses tornado in the background which might interact with my script. Can this be the cause? Can i run tornado in my script with IPython?